A general-purpose decorator - correctly awaiting an awaitable type obtained from Reflection
Preamble: I was looking at how best to implement a general-purpose decorator in C# that copes with async methods. Most examples use DispatcherProxy, which only offers a synchronous Invoke. Unless NET improves this and adds async support, currently closed, we're left with calling this in a way that works the same way as a normal specific decorator. The problem seems to be that because of the decision to make awaitables be a pattern, there's no clean way to detect this circumstance and write the code correctly, but I'm hoping someone more familiar with the depths of Reflection can shine a light.
A specific easy example first:
interface IMyWork
{
  Task DoStuff();
}

class MyWork : IMyWork
{
  public async Task DoStuff() { await Something(); }
}

// A decorator like any other
class MyDecoratedWork : IMyWork
{
  private readonly MyWork _real;

  public Task DoStuff()
  {
    using var scope = Decorate();
    await _real.Something();
    // Disposal is in the same context as Decorate was - things like AsyncLocal are restored
  }

  private IDisposable Decorate() { /* return some scoped decoration /* }
}

That's easy if you want to write decorators manually, but if you've got lots of these to write, it becomes appealing to have a general-purpose decorator. Examples tend to look like this:
class DispatchProxyScopedDecorator<TDecorated> : DispatchProxy
{
  private TDecorated? _decorated;
  private IScopeProvider? _scopeProvider;

  private void SetParameters(TDecorated decorated, IScopeProviderscopeProvider)
  {
    _decorated = decorated;
    _scopeProvider = scopeProvider;
  }

  protected override object? Invoke(MethodInfo? targetMethod, object?[]? args)
  {
    // The important bit
  }

  public static TDecorated Create(TDecorated decorated, IScopeProvider scopeProvider)
  {
    object created = Create<TDecorated, DispatchProxyScopedDecorator<TDecorated>>()!;
    ((DispatchProxyScopedDecorator<TDecorated>)created).SetParameters(decorated, scopeProvider);

    return (TDecorated)created;
  }
}

The synchronous case is easy:
protected override object? Invoke(MethodInfo? targetMethod, object?[]? args)
{
  using var scope = _scopeProvider.Decorate();
  return targetMethod?.Invoke(_decorated, args);
}

but Invoke is a synchronous method, which means to correctly decorate a method call that returns an awaitable, the return type has to be intercepted with a new awaitable.
The only requirement appears to be implementing a method GetAwaiter (things like AsyncStateMachineAttribute don't necessarily apply).
var scope = _scopeProvider.Decorate();

var result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);

if (result is null)
{
  return null;
}

// This isn't complete - also needs to hunt through assemblies for extension methods!
var awaiterMethod = result.GetType().GetMethod("GetAwaiter");

If this isn't null, I've got an awaitable. My ideal in terms of simple-to-maintain code would be to just drop this into an async method and let the compiler do the hard work:
async Task InterceptAsync(??? awaitable, MyScope scope)
{
  try
  {
    await awaitable;
  }
  finally
  {
    scope.Dispose();
  }
}

if (awaiterMethod is not null)
{
  return InterceptAsync(result, scope);
}

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile for obvious reasons - since an awaitable is not a single type, there's nothing I can supply to ??? that the compiler will accept (other than maybe dynamic, but that's deprecated).
There are obvious downsides as with any decorator (performance, potential change of return type), but is this even feasible? Am I missing some other approach? My immediate thought is that if the original code isn't returning a Task, the above would violate the expected method signature - but does that mean every single different awaitable requires its own implementation?
Thoughts appreciated.

Do you actually need to support any type of awaitable, and not just Task and Task<T> (and possibly ValueTask and ValueTask<T>).  While the language technically supports other awaitables, they're quire rare.  Is it really unacceptable for you to just not support them in this context?

and why is this code referenced from the github issue not working for you?

@Servy I feel the purpose of the question is to understand whether this is feasible. Custom awaiters may be rare, but the whole point of code like this is to operate invisibly; if it requires special-case code all the time, it's pointless.

@IvanPetrov The linked Github repo does not appear to have been maintained, and has open issues asking about ValueTask & out parameters. As above, I feel like my question is exploring: is this hitting a fundamental language limitation (I note that the referenced code actually emits IL, which implies the language is being exceeded, and also IL emitting is hardly easy to understand or maintain).

@naviwhack So no, it's not actually something you need to do.  Just say that then.

@Servy That's not what I said at all. If a decorator has to understand every awaitable type in use, in any library it might decorate, then hard-coding by e.g. Task & ValueTask isn't workable. So, yes, it does need to understand any awaitable, in an ideal case.

@naviwhack And I asked if you actually had any that you were using, and your response was, "I was just curious if it's possible".  Not that you had even a single use case.  I certainly can't think of any situation in which I would ever want to decorate any other type of awaitable.  Most any feature of...anything...that you see out there will only ever support Task, and on rare occasion ValueTask.

The article by Stephen Toub I linked gave several examples, and indeed I've seen these used in our codebases. I said they're rare, and you keep misinterpreting what I've said to statements like 'Not that you had even a single use case'. I see no further value in engaging.

If all you want to do is call Dispose before you execute the await continuation code in the code consuming your proxy , maybe you could just check for the mandatory INotifyCompletion and then register the scope.Dispose() there.
Something like this:
var scope = _scopeProvider.Decorate();

var result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);

if (result is null)
{
  return null;
}

var awaiterMethod = result.GetType().GetMethod("GetAwaiter");

var awaiter = awaiterMethod.Invoke(result,null)
if(awaiter is INotifyCompletion notifycompl){
   notifycomp.OnCompleted(()=>scope.Dispose());
}

return result;

You would be returning the initial task-like object too, not a Task wrapped one.
This is the general idea:
// the awaitable we intercept
async Task AsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Inside the action/work behind behind the awaitable awaitable");
    throw new Exception();
}

async Task Main()
{
    var task = AsyncMethod();
    // our decorator work
    task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => Console.WriteLine("In Proxy Code: Scope.Disposed()"));

    try
    {
        await task; // the actual use of our proxy
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Real Code");
    }
}

Output:
Inside the action/work behind behind the awaitable awaitable
In Proxy Code: Scope.Disposed()
In Real Code

This wouldn't work if there is a single continuation action maintained internally by the custom awaitable like in this answer, but the wording of INotifyCompletion from the docs and in the comments in the source code:

Represents an operation that schedules continuations when it
completes.

leads me to believe that most implementations should adhere to multiple continuations which will favor our approach here.

Very intriguing! Nice work! I'd need to think about this more, but in principle this looks like it could work. Ultimately any decorator is either executing code before or after the method decorated. The only case I can think of where this might fall down is a desire to chain the awaits (the decorator itself wants to interject async code), but I'm wondering if at that point it becomes a requirement that one understand the actual awaitables involved e.g. Task and continuations, and it's just better to do such a decorator by hand.

@naviwhack look at the updated answer for the when it's gonna be scheduled - just after the code returnsto  the the "real" code after the await.

I'm rather disappointed this got downvoted without comment - if there's a problem with this approach, I think both author and question asker would want to know.

@naviwhack yeah, me too. I'm really curious, if something is overlooked...
